# How to Convert C++ to Objective C in Xcode to compile Box2D?

Tags: c++, objective-c, header-files, box2d-iphone

**Trying to use Box2D for an Iphone App but do not know how to convert the following C++ header file to Xcode Objective C... Would someone please help me? Thank You in Advance!**

```
#include <Box2D/Common/b2Settings.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>

b2Version b2_version = {2, 2, 1};

// Memory allocators. Modify these to use your own allocator.

void* b2Alloc(int32 size){
return malloc(size);
}

void b2Free(void* mem)
{
   free(mem);
}

// You can modify this to use your logging facility.

void b2Log(const char* string, ...)

{
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, string);
   vprintf(string, args);
   va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Except for the headers, all of that code is C, not C++. For example, `malloc`/`free` are C routines. The nearest routines in C++ would be `new`/`delete`.

Unless there is other code you're not showing us, you should be able to simply and safely point to C headers, instead:

```
#include <stdlib.h>   /* was #include <cstdlib> */
#include <stdio.h>    /* was #include <cstdio>  */
#include <stdarg.h>   /* was #include <cstdarg> */
```

...and that chunk of code should compile as C (and therefore within an Objective-C project).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Objective-C++ mode? Rename your `.m`/`.cpp` files to `.mm`